# SSIS 2008 excel connection manager load xlsx file error

Tags: ssis

my system:

Windows server 2008 R2 standard.

visual studio 2008/SQL Server 2008

No Office installed.

When I try to connect to an excel (xlsx) file, I got this error when trying to select the name of a sheet.

```
    TITLE: System.Data
    ------------------------------

    The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Should I install Office (version?) to solve this or is there other solution?

Comment: Yes.  I believe version 12 corresponds to Office 2003, but any version later than that should work.

Comment: Other than the anser belw, I find it also needs to set debug mode in BIDS to 64 bit disabled. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534651/HowplustoplussolveplusSSISpluserrorpluscodeplus-xC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked through the same problem recently. The consensus of the research I conducted says that installing the following should resolve the problem:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

However, if that doesn't work, you may need to install this as well:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

You should not have to install the full blown version of Office on your server. (Besides the fact that doing so is poor practice.)